# Conditional formatting a combobox within a subform

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a conditional format that colors the combobox's background color depending on its value. The combobox is within a subform (if that matters; it shouldn't). For some reason, the conditional format only applies when the combobox has focus. Can anyone tell me what might be going on? I'm assuming this isn't supposed to happen, since I had almost the exact same setup with a text box and the background color is correct whether it has focus or not.

Also my combobox has its rowsource determined by a query in VBA due to a Form_Current() event in case that has anything to do with it (when I comment out the line I have the same problem though).

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds a little like the combobox has a transparent background? In that case it shows its background color (default or formatted) only when it has the focus.

Comment: Oh! Haha uhh... yes. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combobox or textbox with a **transparent background** shows its background color (default or conditionally formatted) only when it has the focus.

Solution: set its `BackStyle` to `Normal`.

Sometimes the answer is much simpler than expected. :-)